# psycopg2: re-using connection object after connection closing

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I could not find a way to re-use a connection object. After executing conn.close() I still have the object in memory so there must be a way to re-use it. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: You don't have the connection to the database open anymore. What would you like to do with the connection object that doesn't involve the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [connection class documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html):

*close()*

*Close the connection now (rather than whenever del is executed). The connection will be unusable from this point forward; an InterfaceError will be raised if any operation is attempted with the connection*

Comment: Does it mean that every time I create a new connection the old one stays in memory?

Comment: Not if you assign the new connection to the same variable; then the object (and memory) gets overwritten. What's the worry though? A closed connection object won't exhaust your memory.